# How to run several batch files without open shell windows?

Tags: batch-file

I've got some `.bat` files with `start xxx` and I need to run them all in another file

so if do `start xxx.bat` there I will get running xxx and command line shell. I don't need another shell so how to run batch file without opening another shell? or close it's shell after executing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you just want to use `call` instead of `start`.

Example:

```
call xxx.bat
```